# How can I represent the X of constellation in LaTeX?

Tags: symbols

I wanted to type this X of constellation in LaTeX.

[image]

But it's neither `\Chi` nor `\chi`.

Comment: it's probably a script X if you have the pdf you can see what fonts are used.

Comment: Please provide an MWE (from `documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) showing what you have done to produce your example text.

Answer (score 5):

This is a calligraphic X in Computer Modern, the default font used in LaTeX. Such a calligraphic font can usually be used with the `\mathcal` command. Here's a minimal document which produces this symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\( \mathcal{X} \)
\end{document}
```

However, if you use font packages, the calligraphic font may be changed by those packages. In that case, you might have to reload Computer Modern's calligraphic font to get this X. The package [`mathalpha`](https://ctan.org/pkg/mathalpha) with option `cal=cm` can be used for this, as shown in the following example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[cal=cm]{mathalpha}
\begin{document}
\( \mathcal{X} \)
\end{document}
```

Both of the above examples output the same minimal document:

[image]